# Do the 'Charizard EX' sets automatically come with a Mega Charizard EX card?

Tags: pokemon

My nine-year-old has asked for a 'Mega Charizard EX set' of Pokémon cards. I googled that. I found the individual Mega Charizard EX card for $20-$25 and I found the Charizard EX set of Pokémon cards. He battles other kids with the cards, of course.

Do the Charizard EX sets automatically come with a Mega Charizard EX? Or do I have to buy the individual card to be sure he'll get THAT particular card?

I want to get it for him for Christmas. It would be a bummer to get the set and not find that card in it on Christmas morning, right? Or am I wrong? Of course, I'd rather not pay so much for a single card...

Comment: The OP's account is already a deleted user after 8 hours?  What did we do?!

Comment: @Nelson I don't think the OP's account is deleted, it is still active on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/201587/mom). Given that it was a migrated question, the OP probably just hasn't join this community yet. I see this a lot when questions are migrated

Comment: @Wondercricket that's got to be confusing for people just joining the site for the first time

Comment: @LateralTerminal - It's why I wish SE treated accounts as 'network-wide' instead of having to 'join and link' individual site accounts. But that's a whole other mess for another time :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### I'll attempt to give you the best help I can with the information you've provided.

This might be a bit confusing to someone who knows nothing about the card game. If you can in the comments or your question, define what you mean when you say "set" and what your child means when they say "set". I suspect you are using "set" to mean a product that includes a "set of cards", and your child is using "set" to either mean a set of one card (2-4 of the same card for use in a deck) or a "set" as in "a set of both".

"Set" can mean one of several things. "Set" could mean he wants a set of both; it could mean he wants a "playset" - a term used in competitive Pokemon indicating having several of one card to use in a deck (generally 2 - 4).

First off, there are two types of "Mega Charizard". One is "Mega Charizard X", which is black and blue. The other is "Mega Charizard Y", which is orange.

---

### Mega Charizard X

(There are two printings of this card. One is from the booster pack series Flashfire; the other is from the booster pack series Generations).

[image]
[image]

---

### Mega Charizard Y

(This one is from the booster pack series XY Evolutions).

[image]

---

It would be useful, if you can, to provide links to the "sets" of product you've found for M Charizard EX. Are these boxes with a single card and packs? Tins? Single cards? The Pokemon TCG includes a lot of product including sealed packs of cards, boxes with certain cards, tins, etc.

When you use "the Charizard EX set of Pokémon cards" I'm assuming you mean a product that includes Charizard EX, which is probably this box:

[image]

If that is the case: **No, this does not come with either M Charizard EX card**. This sealed product comes with four booster packs as shown (which contain random cards, of which M Charizard or any other EX card is fairly rare), a single Charizard EX card, and an oversized version of the card.

Alternatively, you could have found these products on Amazon:

[image]

If *that* is the case: **No, this ALSO does not come with either M Charizard EX card**! This sealed product comes with four booster packs as shown (which contain random cards, of which M Charizard or any other EX card is fairly rare), a single Charizard card (much less valuable than an EX) and a small statue. Also looks like your selection is random!

This also shows up on Amazon!
[image]

Unsurprisingly... **this also will not give you either M Charizard EX card**. Similar to the first box, you'll get four packs, a single Charizard EX, and a jumbo card.

### Regardless of what version your child wants, the only reliable, 100% way to obtain either M Charizard EX card is to buy the single card.

It doesn't look like these were available in any promotional boxes. Buying packs to try and get one is a terrible idea - the odds of getting even a single EX rarity card, of which there are very many, is about 1/6 of these booster packs which retail for around $3-4 each.

Comment: Great first answer!
Welcome aboard.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Thanks! I flew over from Arqade after seeing this migrated - I play the TCG and I can understand how confusing this can be to a parent. Just hope she moves her account over here and can figure out what her child wants!

Comment: Thank You!!!! You have probably saved me a ton of grief. The funny part is that I'll bet my son is more excited about the prospect of "maybe" getting that particular card, but getting a lot of new cards at the very least, than he is about that specific card. I hope.    He's smart enough to understand "odds" and I'm thinking he'd rather have a huge set of different new cards than to have one Mega EX card of a specific type. The sets and the individual Mega EX are about the same price from what I've seen.   And the X and Y is definitely what was tripping me up.  Thank you! Merry Christmas!

Comment: @mom So glad you found this question over here! I was worried that it got lost in the migration. The rare cards can always be a bit of a doozy to get. I'm happy to help - if you want to mark this as the answer to your question, there should be a check mark you can click near my answer to mark it as the answer. Good luck with your son!

Comment: This is going to be a great opportunity to understand probability. Most kids have a hard time in high school because they have never dealt with it in real life.